# Issue with what appears to be cached data

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I load up flask it runs the MYSQL query and gets all servers that are reserved, when I load the page it shows the correct data.

When I change data on the database that should change what the query shows the data stays the same displayed on the page. How can I get it to query the data every time the page is loaded to ensure it has the latest data?

This is my current code:

***`app.py`***:

```
from function import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form.get("server1"):
            return render_template("serverstatus.html", serverstatus=str(start_server('156.38.228.98', 27015)))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('index.html', server_list=list_servers("No"))
```

***`function.py`***:

```
import socket
import time
import mysql.connector as mysql
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

def list_servers(reserved):
    cursor = mysqldata.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM bruce_warmod.wm_server_details WHERE Reserved=\"' + reserved + '\";')
    db_listed_servers = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return db_listed_servers
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're _actually_ updating the database (i.e. that you are properly committing the transaction in which you make the change)?

Comment: I am 100% sure because if i restart flask the web page shows the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers invalidate the cache when you refresh with shift-F5.  You could try that first, and see if it narrows down your problem.

Comment: I am certain its not the browser though it was that and tried other browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a timestamp in your table i.e created_at and then query the latest as per date.

Comment: Will only show the query for the latest just before flask was started wont show anything new after flask is running

Comment: ha got it now.So it almost feels like you want something to enable you to do event driven dev like sockets.Or a simpler solution would be to  create a rest api with an endpoint you can ping every x seconds to get the latest.

Comment: Found the fixed i posted the answer it just feels dirty to code the data like that because what if the password changes

Answer (score 0):

it works if the function is coded like this but i feel its dirty hard coding stuff in functions like that:

```
def list_servers(reserved):
    mysqldata = mysql.connect(host="",
                              user="",
                              passwd="")
    cursor = mysqldata.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM bruce_warmod.wm_server_details WHERE Reserved=\"' + reserved + '\";')
    db_listed_servers = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(db_listed_servers)
    return db_listed_servers
```